# Change Schema Name and Then Change It Back Again

Tags: amazon-redshift

In a clean-up effort, I changed some schema names in Redshift. Then I nearly immediately switched the schema names back. All but a few of the tables disappeared.

Is this a known issue?

Should I be more careful about renaming tables to previous names?

```
sql> ALTER SCHEMA common_schema RENAME TO common_schema_v1
```

> [2019-05-01 14:39:25] completed in 432 ms

```
sql> ALTER SCHEMA common_schema_v1 RENAME TO common_schema
```

> [2019-05-01 14:48:41] completed in 371 ms

Comment: Are you sure the tables actually disappeared and it's not just a caching issue in your client tool? Renaming a schema should not affect the tables in the schema (although it will probably play havoc with any downstream reports, ETL processes etc.)

Comment: We looked on two separate machines and all but two of the tables had been disappeared. :-[]

Comment: If you are 100% sure you should try to replicate and discuss with AWS support. You can also check on table stl_ddltext  to see whether any other commands were issued.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables would not normally be dropped by a rename operation.

It could be the rename changed your search path and you're just not seeing the tables now. Try re-adding the schema name to your search path.

```
SHOW search_path;
SET search_path TO public, common_schema;
```

You can also look for the tables in the catalog to confirm they're still there.

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'common_schema'
;
```

Or

```
SELECT nspname AS schema_name
     , relname AS table_name
FROM pg_class c
   , pg_namespace n 
WHERE n.oid = c.relnamespace 
  AND c.reltype > 0 
  AND n.nspname = 'common_schema' 
ORDER BY 1, 2 
;
```